# BMO1 2011 Problem 1: Find $n$ such that $n^2+20n+11$ is a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

1. Find all (positive or negative) integers
   $n$ for which

$$n^2+20n+11$$

is a perfect square. Remember that you must justify that you have found
them all.

For the first part I did so:

$$n^2+20n+11=M^2 $$ where M is an integer.
That factors down to:
$$ (n+10)^2-M^2=89$$
$$ (n+10-M)(n+10+M)=89$$
From there it is easy to find solutions as 89 is prime and it is a diophantine equation.

So the first part of the question is quite simple, however I am completely stumped on how to do the second part, how might we show that those are the only solutions?

Comment: Maybe if you provide your solution to the first part it would be easier for us to help you with the second part.

Comment: Actually you have done it. You have strarted from the equation and you have *deduced* from it that $n$ must be $35$ or $-55$.

Comment: But how do we justify that these are the only values of n?

Comment: @MishalMrinal What you and ajotatxe proved is that: if $n$ is such that $n^2+20n+11$ is a perfect square, **then** $n$ is **necessarly** either $35$ or $-55$, in other words: $n^2+20n+11\text{ is a perfect square}\Rightarrow n\in\{-55,35\}$. By contraposition: $n\neq 35 \land n\neq -55\Rightarrow n^2+20n+11\text{ isn't a perfect square}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have $n^2+20n+11=(n+10)^2-89$. So our number is $89$ away from some perfect square. What do you know about the difference between consecutive squares? What does that say about the possibility of (not necessarily consecutive) squares that are $89$ away from one another?

Comment: The difference between consecutive squares is $2n-1$. However i didn't quite get your second hint.

Comment: The difference between two squares is therefore a sum of consecutive odd numbers. Now you can just try out in what ways you can make a sum of consecutive odd numbers become $89$. There aren't too many possibilities. Or go with ajotatxe's answer, which I think is better.

Comment: I used the same approach as the answer below, however is doing the same thing outlined below enough of a justification that these are the only solutions for n? How do we confirm that we haven't missed any?

Comment: @MishalMrinal The difference is $2n+1$ ;)

Comment: @Scientifica That depends on whether we have $n^2-(n-1)^2$ or $(n+1)^2-n^2$. Whether it's $+1$ or $-1$ is irrelevant in the end. The important point is that it is an odd number, and for the difference of the next pair of squares, it's the next odd number. So I'd say $2n-1$ is a good answer, and there is no need for you to correct it.

Comment: @Arthur Indeed you're right. I didn't pay attention to that, my bad.

Comment: Hmmm, guess I am overthinking it a little, just seemed a little to easy for a BMO problem. Well it is problem 1 after all, thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 8):

Note that
$$n^2+20n+11=(n+10)^2-89$$
so we have to find all the pairs of squares $a^2$, $b^2$ such that $a^2-b^2=89$. Of course, $a$ and $b$ are integers. We see that $|a|>|b|$.

Since $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ and $89$ is a prime number, then we have these possibilities:

- $a+b=89$ and $a-b=1$, that is, $a=45$, $b=44$.
- $a+b=1$ and $a-b=89$, that is, $a=45$, $b=-44$.
- $a+b=-89$ and $a-b=-1$, that is, $a=-45$, $b=-44$.
- $a+b=-1$ and $a-b=-89$, that is, $a=-45$, $b=44$.

So clearly, $a^2=2025$ and $b^2=1936$.

Then $n+10=\pm45$ which gives two values for $n$, namely $n=35$ and $n=-55$.

**EDIT**: How can be proved that there are no more solutions?

Indeed, this is already done. Our reasoning is like this:

- Proposition $A$: "$n$ is such that $n^2-20n+11$ is a perfect square".
- Proposition $B$: "$n$ is $35$ or $-55$".

We have shown, assuming that $n$ is integer, that $A$ implies $B$. So if $n$ is another integer number, $B$ is false. Hence, $A$ is false. That is, if $n$ is not $35$ or $-55$ then $n^2+20n+11$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: I already did that part.....any help with the last part?

Comment: Read my comment to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Let $n^2+20n+11=(n+m)^2$

$\iff n=\dfrac{m^2-11}{2(10-m)}$

So, $m$ must be odd $=2r+1$(say)

$\implies n=\dfrac{2r^2+2r-5}{9-2r}$

Now if integer $d(>0)$ divides both $2r^2+2r-5,9-2r$

$d$ must divide $r(9-2r)+(2r^2+2r-5)=11r-5$

$d$ must divide $11(9-2r)+2(11r-5)=89$

As $n$ is an integer,  $9-2r$ must divide $89$ whose factors are $\pm1,\pm89$